# While doing "RESET PC" in Windows 10, will my partitions other than C drive will be affected?

Tags: windows, windows-10, reset

I plan to use the RESET PC feature in WINDOWS 10 in my laptop.
I want to reinstall windows 10 in my C drive and dont want to keep any previous 
files in C drive or any system settings.

- After clicking RESET PC, I get two options
  (1) Keep my files
  (2) Remove Everything

If I choose Remove Everything >> and then choose JUST REMOVE MY FILES

Will choosing JUST REMOVE MY FILES affect my other partitions? Will I lose data in my other partitions?

Comment: depends if you've moved your users folder(s) to other drives. Safest bet is to backup, backup then backup again to an external drive just in case. Or, disconnect the SATA cables for the drives other than C: (unless you've partitioned the disk)

Comment: It's a laptop and I don't need anything from the USER folder(s).
I have three partitions C, D and E. My data is only in D and E.